# How to use threading.local() correctly to pass values?

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

Why does this code work:

```
data = local()

def main():
  proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = foo)
  proc.start()

def foo():
  data.stuff = 'happiness'
  bar()

def bar():
  print data.stuff
```

But this code does not work?

```
def main():
  proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = foo)
  proc.start()

def foo():
  local().stuff = 'happiness'
  bar()

def bar():
  print local().stuff
```

We have code divided to several modules and it has multiple threads. We need to pass values to the threads that need to presist in all those modules.

For instance:

We instantiate a parcel of work.

```
# inside module_name_a.py 
work = Work(a, b, c)
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = work.do_this)
proc.start()
```

We are doing this work and we need to store some data globally in the thread. We can't change the API of Detail.

```
# inside work_module_b.py 
class Work():
  .
  .
  .
  def do_this():
    detail = Detail(x, y, z)
    local().stuff = 'important'
    detail.handle_this()
```

We need the body of `handle_this()` to "see" the values inside `threading.local()`

```
# inside detail_module_b.py 
class Detail():
  .
  .
  .
  def do_this():
    detail = Detail(x, y, z)
    local().stuff = 'important'
    detail.handle_this()
```

Any advice about proper use of threading.local() ?

Comment: Are you using standard C Python? If so, your title might be misleading since C Python doesn't really do multithreading.

Comment: @Tyler fixed the tag and title

Comment: Use `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing.Process`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#miscellaneous) states `multiprocessing contains no analogues of [...] threading.local.`

Comment: @Vincent Thanks. How do you close a question?

Comment: This post explain it well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408171/thread-local-storage-in-python

Comment: It all makes sense, there is no point for threading local when with different processes you just have different globals anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call local() you get a new thread-local instance. If you call it twice, you've got two different local objects.

It's like doing

```
new Car().setColor(red)
new Car().getColor()
```

Your example calls local twice, so you're dealing with two different objects.

```
def main():
  proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = foo)
  proc.start()

def foo():
  local().stuff = 'happiness'
  bar()

def bar():
  print local().stuff
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html