# Re-initiate decorator's argument in a decorated method

Tags: python, methods, decorator

Suppose you have a decorator which accepts an argument as an input `decor(N)`.
This decorator is used to decorate a method within a module `funcs.py`

```
# funcs.py

@decor(N=10)    
def testMethod():
# do something
return something
```

This `funcs.py` module is now imported in `main.py` where `testMethod` is called.

```
# main.py

import funcs as funcs

funcs.testMethod()
```

Question: How can I alter `N` from `main.py' ?

My attemp was to set `N` as an attribute of `funcs.py` , but when I tried to alter this attribute `funcs.N = 20` within `main.py`, `funcs.testMethod` run with `N=10`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does python allow me to pass dynamic variables to a decorator at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789212/does-python-allow-me-to-pass-dynamic-variables-to-a-decorator-at-runtime)

Comment: Not really, as i was looking a way to alter the decorator's argument without passing it in my testMethod argument's at all. Anyway, i worked it another way around. I ll post it below as an answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was this. I removed the argument from the decorator, and i handled it as an argument from the `main.py`

```
# funcs.py

N=10

def decor(function):
    def run_function_for_some_N(*args, **kwargs):
        if N == 10:
            print(f'N = {N}. Run testMethod ')
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('N != 10. Will not run testMethod')
    return run_function_for_some_N

@decor
def testMethod():
    print('hello world')
```

I can now alter `N` from `main.py`

```
# main.py

import funcs as funcs

for funcs.N in [10,11]:
    funcs.testMethod()
```

Output

```
N = 10. Run testMethod 
hello world
N != 10. Will not run testMethod
```