# Flask contexts (application and request) vs thread-local variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-multithreading

[Flask Web Development](http://flaskbook.com/) says:

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/')
def index():
  user_agent = request.headers.get('User-Agent')
  return '<p>Your browser is %s</p>' % user_agent
```

> Note how in this view function `request` is used as if it was a global
>   variable. In reality, `request` cannot be a global variable if you
>   consider that in a multithreaded server the threads are working on
>   different requests from different clients at the same time, so each
>   thread needs to see a different object in request. Contexts enable
>   Flask to make certain variables globally accessible to a thread
>   without interfering with the other threads.

Understandable, but why not simply make `request` a [thread-local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408171/thread-local-storage-in-python)? Under the hood, what exactly is `request`, and how is it different from a thread-local variable?

Comment: because thread-local variable cannot distinguish greenlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was simply a design decision by Armin (the author of Flask). You could indeed rewrite Flask to operate as a thread-local, but that was not what he wanted to do here.

The idea of Flask (in general) is to keep things as simple as possible, and abstract a lot of thinking away. This is why a lot of Flask helpers are implemented as 'global variables': you don't really have to think about the meaning behind it, because each global is bound to the incoming request.

Comment: I just realized I don't understand how `session` works if it's thread-local, so I asked it as a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818350/does-flask-session-variable-maintain-state-across-threads)