# Does flask session variable maintain state across threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

According to the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#sessions):

> A session basically makes it possible to remember information from one
>   request to another.

But elsewhere, [the docs say](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/reqcontext/#how-the-context-works) that `session` is local to a thread. So if `flask` is used in a multithreaded environment (say, `app.run(threaded=True)`), how can it fulfill this promise?

I only see two alternatives:

- `flask` somehow ensures that the same user session is always serviced by the same thread (which seems horrible because a single user browsing in two tabs would have to wait for his first request to finish before his second request is handled)
- `session` is completely useless if I allow threads, and I need to store session-specific information in a database (which seems rather unexpected and isn't mentioned in the docs)

Am I missing something?

Edit: I guess another alternative is:

- `session` itself is a thread-local variable from python perspective (i.e., python sees each thread's `session` as completely independent objects), but it is somehow synchronized across threads by `flask` (presumably with some process-global in-memory data structure). In that case, `flask` could make all modifications to `session` atomic (using some inter-thread synchronization mechanism).

Update: based on @Daniel Roseman answer, my last guess was correct, except flask doesn't do it itself but rather asks the user agent to store / retrieve persistent state (and thus, the state is not per *flask process* or per *flask application* but rather per whatever collection of requests the user agent happens to persist the state over - what one might call *user session*).

Comment: uses cookies unless you implement a backend session middleware

Comment: @reptilicus but cookies don't actually store any state data for a session, AFAIK. The only store a unique identifier for a session. Any state info has to be stored on the `session` variable. So while multiple threads might be aware it's the same session, they won't have access to the data written on `session` variable by other threads. Which defeats the whole purpose of `session` variable.

Comment: you can store whatever you want basically. it basically acts like a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *very next sentence* after the one you quoted:

> The way Flask does this is by using a signed cookie.

Flask stores the information in the cookie before sending the response, and reads it back at the beginning of the next request.

Comment: Does the cookie store the entire contents of the `session` dictionary?! Isn't that super dangerous, and also slow if the data is large?

Comment: And also cookie max size is 4K, so it can store only a tiny amount of data, then?

Comment: Flask of course only stores a token in the cookie. The session data is kept server-side.

Comment: max cookie size varies by browser, but yes there is a limit

Comment: @DominikGeorge the *very next sentence* after the one Daniel quoted indicates the opposite: *"So the user can look at the session contents, but not modify it unless they know the secret key"*. That doesn't sound like it's just a token that's being stored.

Comment: @DominikGeorge also this post heavily implies Flask is actually using client-side sessions, storying the payload in the cookie (signed, to make it tamper proof): http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/

Comment: Thats true, its basically a key-value store. You can look at the session cookie in your browser developer tools for the request. Its crypto signed with the app's `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Yes, by default flask uses client side sessions with a cryptographically signed cookie. The code is here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.11-maintenance/flask/sessions.py

Comment: @LukasGraf You are right - code supports that. I really mixed that up with another Flask session implementation somehow.

Comment: @DominikGeorge probably https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/ - *"an extension for Flask that adds support for Server-side Session to your application"* ;-)

Comment: Yeah exactly that. Got confused by `Flask-Session` vs. `flask.sessions`. What kind of unlucky naming is that, anyway ;)?

Comment: So at every request, the user sends cookie to the server?

Comment: So can session be used to store data between requests in a multi threaded environment?