# local per-thread storage in Python Celery?

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, storage, local

Does Celery support per-worker local storage?

the reason I ask is: I need to use GPU for lots of small tasks, and allocating-and-deallocating GPU thread is dominating the computation time.

I have tried `threadLocal = threading.local()` as per [Thread local storage in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408171/thread-local-storage-in-python)

but it appears that each new call gets a fresh thread . . . .