# What is the difference (in terms of its purpose) between using thread local and a local variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
mydata = threading.local()
mydata.x = 1
```

Thread-local data is data whose values are thread specific.

A local variable in a thread for example (`x=10`) is also thread specific.

What is the difference between using thread local and a local variable?

Comment: A thread is not necessarily one single function, there can be multiple functions in a thread working with some shared data.

Comment: The scope is different. Local variables stop to exist when the corresponding function returns. Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408171/thread-local-storage-in-python

Comment: The difference is that a local variable does not survive method scope but a thread-local variable does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it’s important to distinguish **variables** from **objects**.  Each variable refers to an object (never another variable) and can in general be changed to refer to a different object; each object has some number of variables (*e.g.*, dictionary entries, or attributes) and perhaps other data (like an integer’s value).

Every variable is associated with some object; local variables can be considered to be associated with a stack **frame**.  *A fortiori*, a local variable is indeed specific to a thread, but a `threading.local` is an **object** (which can’t be thread-local) whose variables (attributes) are thread-local.  Unlike a local variable, it is therefore possible to have a reference to a `threading.local`, so it can be **shared** among multiple users of an object (typically a module or an instance of a user-defined class).  If those users are on different threads, each sees its own value for the associated variables (really, for the **set** of variables itself).

Comment: I get your point about variables and object, but what I don't understand is why is there such a concept of `threading.local` when we can always create a variable (to hold any object) within a thread? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @variable: Do the last two sentences not help in that regard?

Comment: Say I have a function FnX that will run in a thread. A variable declared in this function will be available to the entire function code. But the modules will be able to use this only via a function for example accepting this variable. So what you are saying is that - the threading local will be globally available in all the code running in the thread (like modules, etc). Have I got it right?

Comment: @variable: That sounds about right: you can (perhaps “before your threads start”) create the thread-local object, publish it (perhaps as a module attribute, also known as a global variable), and then use it from multiple threads.