# Thread local storage in python across multiple classes

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to use thread local storage across multiple classes.

But `threading.local()` gets me a new instance of storage every time I call it. Is there a way to use

```
threading.local().__setattr__('r_id', uuid.uuid4())
```

And there an equivalent of somehow to access in a completely different class ?

```
threading.local().__getattribute__('r_id')
```

Comment: Here you can find your ans

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find your ans

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104983/what-is-thread-local-storage-in-python-and-why-do-i-need-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403471/efficient-way-to-determine-whether-a-particular-function-is-on-the-stack-in-pyth/1403485#1403485)

Here you can find something interesting as well

[Efficient way to determine whether a particular function is on the stack in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403471/efficient-way-to-determine-whether-a-particular-function-is-on-the-stack-in-pyth/1403485#1403485)